# What action should I use for create_or_update operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, crud

Rails has basic REST operation create/update/show/destroy, but if I want an action that create or update existing record should I create my custom action for this ?

I know rails has `first_or_initialize`, but it doesn't seem to fit into definition of create or update.

In my understanding `create` should make a new record and not update existing one and `update` should update without create a new one.

**Here is an example:**

I have model `Blog`, `Tag`, and a join table `Blog_Tags` which reference to `blog_id`, `tag_id`, and a `user_id` to record who suggest this tag to this blog post.

```
[Blog]>-[Blog_Tag]-<[Tag]
             |
         [User]
```

**My thought**

I'm thinking of new action `PUT` `create_or_update` for this example and the route would be and I have routes `blog/[blog_id]/tag/[tag_id_to_add]/create_or_update`. Don't know it is a right way or not.

Comment: No. Do not attempt to add your own methods. Do not do odd things just to avoid multiple requests. Also, PUT might be what you want. It will create a resource at the given URI, or update (replace) an existing resource at that URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up have path like blog/[blog_id]/tag/[tag_id]/suggest which go to dedicate controller `SuggestionController` where I define suggest action there.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in create or update makes no difference.  I would choose update since the method will be calling update.  Just make sure it's clearly documented that the action can create and update a model.

```
def update
   user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: user_params[:email])
   user.update_attributes(user_params)
end
```

As for the verb, the update action for a defined resource should have a POST/PUT verbs by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: find_or_initialize or find_or_create

```
For example, in Rails 4 syntax:

  blog = Blog.find_or_initialize_by(name: "abc")
  blog.update(name: "xyz")

Rails 3:

  blog = Blog.find_or_initialize_by_name("abc")
  blog.update_attributes(name: "xyz")
```

If the record is newly initialised update or update_attributes will attempt to save it.

You can read this link http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by